# Office 365 Unified API "The HTTP header Content-Type is missing or its value is invalid."

Tags: office365, office365api

Attempting upload to OneDrive for Business using the unified API, and the latest API changes. Following this guide: https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_post.htm, I'm attempting to upload a file to OneDrive, but receiving "The HTTP header Content-Type is missing or its value is invalid.". I'm using the exact example found on that page, which does include a content-type header. Is there something I need to do differently?

Answer (score 0):

Multipart upload is not supported right now via graph.microsoft.com. It is coming soon. In the mean time you can upload files up to 4mb by posting to: https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/me/drive/root/children/{filename}/content, the header you need to set is content-type: application/json